# Jasper Reports - calculation of total using CalculationEnum.System

Tags: jasper-reports

### I have 3 columns (obtained from the query along with the data)

### | A | B  |  C |

### | 5 | 15 | 20 |

### | 15| 25 | 40 |

The net total for these columns are to be calculated as below :- 
20 40 0.5 (i.e , the total of C = total of A / total of B) . How do I get the total calculated as required in jasper reports using java .

For calculating the total of column 'C' , I have set the calculation enum constant to be `calculationEnum.SYSTEM` . On setting the expression to be

`expression.setText("new Double($F{" +A + "/" +B +"}.doubleValue())");` , it shows that the corresponding field , `new Double($F{A/B}.doubleValue())` does not exist . To eliminate this , I have added the field in the list of field columns . But then it shows that the column for the corresponding field doesnot exist .

Is what I have done until now correct ? Or is there any better way in which I can get the total to be calculated as required .

Comment: Do you still have issues with this?

Comment: No . The solution works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field A and B need to be of `class="java.lang.Number"` or one of its sub classes as `java.lang.Double`

To get the sum of them the expression is:

```
$F{A}.doubleValue() + $F{B}.doubleValue()
```

To calculate the `SUM($F{A}) / SUM($F{B})` you need to use two variables

```
<variable name="sumOfA" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{A}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="sumOfB" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{B}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

And then in the `textField` do the division, remember to set `evaluationTime="Report"` on the `textField` so that the variables have been calculated before displaying.

```
 <textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="208" y="17" width="100" height="20" uuid="414e6633-58c5-4081-a04b-fe3973f29d96"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{A}.doubleValue()/$V{B}.doubleValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
  </textField>
```

Comment: I did as u said . But while calculating the total (as mentioned in the question ("/" )) , it is calculating as follow :- it is dividing the value of A with b for each and every row present and then summing up the result . But what I required is the total of A divided by total of B .

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables, one for sum of A and one for sum of B.
And then add a text field with the following expression:

```
($V{sumOfA}/$V{sumOfB})
```